# Is there a way to specify an "empty" C# lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'd like to declare an "empty" lambda expression that does, well, nothing.
Is there a way to do something like this without needing the `DoNothing()` method?

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    SomeMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(
            x => DoNothing(),
            x => CanSomeMenuCommandExecute());
}

private void DoNothing()
{
}

private bool CanSomeMenuCommandExecute()
{
    // this depends on my mood
}
```

My intent in doing this is only control the enabled/disabled state of my WPF command, but that's an aside. Maybe it's just too early in the morning for me, but I imagine there must be a way to just declare the `x => DoNothing()` lambda expression in some way like this to accomplish the same thing:

```
SomeMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(
    x => (),
    x => CanSomeMenuCommandExecute());
```

Is there some way to do this? It just seems unnecessary to need a do-nothing method.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

```
Action doNothing = () => { };
```

Comment: Does there exist a predefined empty lambda? I think that it is a bad idea performance wise to create an empty lambda every time I need it. E.g. in JQuery [there is the `noop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069345/what-real-purpose-does-noop-serve-in-jquery-1-4) and I would expect something similar to be present in C#.

Comment: So is an async version of this require the verbose `Func<Task> doNothing = async() => await Task.CompletedTask;`?

Answer (score 27):

I thought I would add some code that I've found useful for this type of situation. I have an `Actions` static class and a `Functions` static class with some basic functions in them:

```
public static class Actions
{
  public static void Empty() { }
  public static void Empty<T>(T value) { }
  public static void Empty<T1, T2>(T1 value1, T2 value2) { }
  /* Put as many overloads as you want */
}

public static class Functions
{
  public static T Identity<T>(T value) { return value; }

  public static T0 Default<T0>() { return default(T0); }
  public static T0 Default<T1, T0>(T1 value1) { return default(T0); }
  /* Put as many overloads as you want */

  /* Some other potential methods */
  public static bool IsNull<T>(T entity) where T : class { return entity == null; }
  public static bool IsNonNull<T>(T entity) where T : class { return entity != null; }

  /* Put as many overloads for True and False as you want */
  public static bool True<T>(T entity) { return true; }
  public static bool False<T>(T entity) { return false; }
}
```

I believe this helps improve readability just a tiny bit:

```
SomeMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(
        Actions.Empty,
        x => CanSomeMenuCommandExecute());

// Another example:
var lOrderedStrings = GetCollectionOfStrings().OrderBy(Functions.Identity);
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this again!

Comment: Can you verify that this only creates one instance of an Action? I.e. calling the generic Actions.Empty twice (given the same delegate type) creates only one instance rather than two?

Comment: This will create more objects than needed ([example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBBmABM3AYVwG9NcL88EAWXAQQAoBKU8yjgEQHsBlAFwCuAM2GMEKJAGcAdAFEwAB34BPZgG52FAL5aq+OgCEWbDBy58ho8ZNkLlazWcq7nFHAdw8BIsRKS4EADG/FDcMKwAvAB8gSFhMCxOrh4EnKYcqXQAsiZkbubeVn628kqqGnqumdR0Rb42AcGh4VGxzQlJmCnUKABs+AH+Upj5Nfj9nvaqea7aQA===))

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
SomeMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(
    x => {},
    x => CanSomeMenuCommandExecute());
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you only need a delegate (rather than an expression tree) then this should work:

```
SomeMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(
        x => {},
        x => CanSomeMenuCommandExecute());
```

(That won't work with expression trees as it's got a *statement body*. See section 4.6 of the C# 3.0 spec for more details.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand why do you need a DoNothing method.

Can't you just do:

```
SomeMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(
                null,
                x => CanSomeMenuCommandExecute());
```

Comment: That is probably checked and will probably throw a NRE.

Comment: I think Dykam is right, but I just didn't think about passing null :-)

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted? Jorge makes a valid point, although it would have been a small effort to check it.

Comment: +1, this is a valid solution, just that the null checking should be extended in `new RelayCommand(..`.

Comment: Imagine what you would need to do in the method using that "null" Action....checking if (action == null) action(); every time.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with C# 9.0 you can specify discards `_` for required parameters. Example:

```cs
Action<int, string, DateTime> action = (_, _, _) => { };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Action DoNothing = delegate { };
Action DoNothing2 = () => {};
```

I used to initialize Events to a do nothing action so it was not null and if it was called without subscription it would default to the 'do nothing function' instead of a null-pointer exception.

```
public event EventHandler<MyHandlerInfo> MyHandlerInfo = delegate { };
```