# What is the use of jQuery.noop() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was going through one `Backbone.js` plugin in which I found the below piece of code.

```
callbacks : {
    search : $.noop,
    valueMatches : $.noop
}
```

What is the `$.noop()` function doing here?

Comment: it is an [empty function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/), which doesn't do anything, this is used so that you don't have to check whether the option is undefined before calling it

Comment: Why not using `function() {}` directly? Because there is already a cached one used by jQuery already. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What real purpose does $.noop() serve in jQuery 1.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069345/what-real-purpose-does-noop-serve-in-jquery-1-4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$.noop` is an empty function so in your case it's returning an empty function

> You can use this empty function when you wish to pass around a
>   function that will do nothing.
>
> This is useful for plugin authors who offer optional callbacks; in the
>   case that no callback is given, something like jQuery.noop could
>   execute.

Documentation found here : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noop/