# what is one example of the usage of the jquery noop function

Tags: javascript, jquery

extending this link [What is the use of jQuery.noop() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572738/what-is-the-use-of-jquery-noop-function)

```
You can use this empty function when you wish to pass 
around a function that will do nothing.

This is useful for plugin authors who offer optional callbacks; 
in the case that no callback is given, something like jQuery.noop could execute.
```

what does it mean by plugin authors who offer optional callbacks, an example will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, a plugin with optional done fail and always callbacks:

```
options: {
    done: $.noop,
    fail: $.noop,
    always: $.noop
}
```

now the plugin author can assume that there is a callback defined for each even if the developer using the plugin doesn't pass one.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L577

Comment: Though in most cases it's safer to just leave it undefined and test for it, when you assume, it leads to errors when the plugin is used incorrectly (which may or may not be a bad thing)

Comment: so u can almost say its a shorthand for function(){}

Comment: that's exactly what it is.