# What does c# lambda cfg => {} mean?

Tags: c#, lambda

I know that x => x + 1 mean create a anonymous function returning x + 1 but what does 
cfg => {} ;
mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743013/is-there-a-way-to-specify-an-empty-c-sharp-lambda-expression

Comment: [Read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb397687.aspx) complete documentation about Lambda Expression.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lambda that does nothing (i.e it's a void method that does no work).

This might be required for a method that requires an action delegate but you don't need the callback to do anything, so you just throw in an empty lambda to achieve the result.

Comment: and in that case, you wouldn't even need to name it, you could have written () => {}, which is an anonymous lambda that takes no parameters and returns no result.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the delegate type that expression is supposed to represent.

The general syntax of a lamda expression is in the form:

```
[params] => [expression]
```

or

```
[params] => { [method body] }
```

So you know what `x => x + 1` means, but it's also equivalent to `x => { return x + 1; }`, provided it's assigned to a variable of type `Func<TInput, TOutput>`.

Given that, `cfg => {}` is a lamda that takes some input and returns nothing, provided it's assigned to avariable of type `Action<TInput>`.  Remember, actions have no return type and the return statement is optional for such methods.