# Create empty lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Consider the function:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Purchases>> GetPurchases(User user, Expression<Func<Purchases, bool>> whereClause)
    {           
            using (var context = new UserDbContext())
            {
                context.Users.Attach(user);
                context.Entry(user).Collection(p => p.Purchases)
                .Query()
                .Where(whereClause)
                .Load();

                if (Equals(user.Purchases, null))
                    return new List<Purchases>();
            }

        return user.Purchases;
}
```

In this function the parameter *whereClause* can at times be `null`, I'm wanting to check if its null and then assign an empty Expression if so. This is as close as I've come:

```
if (Equals(whereClause, null))
       whereClause = () => { };
```

This was based on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743013/is-there-a-way-to-specify-an-empty-c-sharp-lambda-expression), but for the line that makes *whereClause* empty I'm getting the error.

> Error 7   Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type
>   'System.Func'<'Purchases,bool>'

Anyone know how this could be corrected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Not all code paths return a value" means your lambda isn't returning anything. I mean, it's got only one code path, and it's not a long one.

[`Where` requires a lambda which takes one parameter, and returns `bool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx). `Where` won't *let* you give it an empty lambda expression.

You need to give it something it can use to filter items with.

That's actually easy:

```
if (Equals(whereClause, null))
    whereClause = o => true;
```

That's a where clause that always returns `true`, regardless of what you give it. That's probably what you want: If there's no filter, include everything. For each item in the enumeration, one at a time, `Where` gives the lambda the item as `o`. If the lambda returns `true`, it includes that value of `o` in the results.

If you want a null filter to return no items, just return false instead:

```
if (Equals(whereClause, null))
    //  Whatever it is, I'm against it.
    whereClause = o => false;
```

Answer (score 1):

`whereClause` must return a boolean value to use it in LinQs [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method.

Assuming you don't want to filter the list (include all items) you must return `true`, otherwise `false`:

```
if (Equals(whereClause, null))
     whereClause = () => true;
```

Notice: The `{` and `}` are not necessary if you only return a value with a single statement.

But you should know that the most framework methods don't work in this way. They would throw an [`ArgumentNullException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of setting a value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when `whereClause` is null you don't want to apply any filter.

```
        using (var context = new UserDbContext())
        {
            context.Users.Attach(user);
            context.Entry(user).Collection(p => p.Purchases)
            .Query()
            .Where(whereClause ?? p => true)
            .Load();

            if (Equals(user.Purchases, null))
                return new List<Purchases>();
        }
```